# Idiomatic way of avoiding both: memory leak & ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator

I wrote a recursive algorithm that basically looks like the following. I'm using a `Map<Integer, Long>` as a poor's man bag/multiset. In order to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` I'm never removing/adding keys from the map. It works fine and the fact elements keys of `0` occurrences aren't removed doesn't matter in this context.

PS: I know it doesn't scale, it was just a fun/generic way of solving the Advent of Code Day 1 part 1 & 2.

```
Optional<Integer> solve(final Map<Integer, Long> intOccurrences, final int sum, final int addendsCount) {
    if (addendsCount < 1) return Optional.empty();
    if (addendsCount == 1) {
        return intOccurrences.getOrDefault(sum, 0L) > 0 ? Optional.of(sum) : Optional.empty();
    }

    for (val entry : intOccurrences.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() < 1) continue;
        val left = entry.getKey();
        val delta = sum - left;

        changeCountOf(intOccurrences, left, -1);

        val result = solve(intOccurrences, delta, addendsCount - 1);

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            return Optional.of(left * result.get());
        }

        changeCountOf(intOccurrences, left, 1);
    }

    return Optional.empty();

}
```

Since I haven't written java for several years I decided to practice by cleaning up the above algorithm by implementing an `IntBag`. I've implemented the `IntBag` with a `Map<Integer, Count>` backing map which implements `Iterable<Occurrence>`. The custom iterator is backed by the map's `entrySet` iterator and skips over values of `0` occurrences.

Everything works just fine, but while my current `IntBag` implementation plays well with recursive backtracking algorithms, it also leaks memory because entries of `0` occurrences are never cleaned-up.

### QUESTIONS

1. Is there an alternative way to implement a bag that wouldn't suffer from this memory leak problem while avoiding a `CurrentModificationException` (which doesn't involve copying the whole bag)?
2. If my current implementation makes sense, what would be some suitable approaches to cleanup entries? I thought of running a GC process after a certain threshold for instance, but I'm not sure which threshold would make sense, etc.
3. I thought of marking entries for deletion during iterations and then cleanup after all iterations are done, but I don't think there's a way to guarantee iterations are all done if I implement `Iterable`. I could probably work out something if I only implement `forEach` though, where the cleanup would occur after the outer-most `forEach` exits (values of 0 occurrences still need to be ignored during iteration).
4. None of the above would solve the problem of adding new values while iterating recursively. I can't think of an approach that would work other than copying the whole bag right now? Hopefully adding items while iterating is not very common I guess...

The `IntBag` implementation currently looks like this (haven't implemented add/remove since it wasn't necessary):

```
final class IntBag implements Iterable<IntBag.Occurrence> {
    private final Map<Integer, Count> occurrenceMap;

    private IntBag(final Map<Integer, Count> occurrenceMap) {
        this.occurrenceMap = occurrenceMap;
    }

    boolean contains(final int value) {
        return !occurrenceMap.getOrDefault(value, Count.ZERO).isZero();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Occurrence> iterator() {
        return new IntBag.BagIterator(occurrenceMap.entrySet().iterator());
    }

    static IntBag of(final List<Integer> values) {
        return new IntBag(countInts(values));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Count> countInts(final List<Integer> values) {
        return values.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), reducing(Count.ZERO, e -> Count.ONE, Count::merge)));
    }

    private static final class BagIterator implements Iterator<Occurrence> {
        private final Iterator<Entry<Integer, Count>> entryIterator;
        private Entry<Integer, Count> nextEntry;

        BagIterator(@NonNull final Iterator<Entry<Integer, Count>> entryIterator) {
            this.entryIterator = entryIterator;
            initNext();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextEntry != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Occurrence next() {
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            val currentEntry = nextEntry;
            initNext();
            return new Occurrence(currentEntry);
        }

        private void initNext() {
            while(entryIterator.hasNext()) {
                val maybeNext = entryIterator.next();
                if (maybeNext.getValue().isZero()) continue;
                nextEntry = maybeNext;
                return;
            }

            nextEntry = null;
        }
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static final class Occurrence {
        private final Map.Entry<Integer, Count> entry;

        int value() {
            return entry.getKey();
        }

        long count() {
            return entry.getValue().value();
        }

        void merge(final long modifier) {
            entry.setValue(entry.getValue().merge(modifier));
        }
    }

    private static final class Count {
        private final long value;

        private Count(final long value) {
            this.value = Math.max(0L, value);
        }

        long value() {
            return value;
        }

        boolean isZero() {
            return value == 0L;
        }

        Count merge(@NonNull final Count modifier) {
            return merge(modifier.value());
        }

        Count merge(final long modifier) {
            return new Count(value + modifier);
        }

        static final Count ZERO = Count.of(0L);
        static final Count ONE = Count.of(1L);
        static Count of(final long value) {
            return new Count(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest moving the question to [codereview](codereview.stackexchange.org) - because you are looking for suggestions on how to make your (pretty good already) code better, rather than getting it to work in the first place.